# Redirecting the output of a window to another window in Windows 8

Tags: opencv, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using OpenCV for my Windows 8 App. I am using image recognition algorithms of OpenCV and the output is displayed on an OpenCV window. I want to redirect that output to my app's window. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you submit a screenshot and some code?

Comment: I'm basically doing this - http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

Comment: you must have sent some Mat to that opencv window before. why not reuse that instead ?

Comment: The above link doesn't work. Here's the correct one: http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/